# I need to dynamically shift my array in order of the options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

## My Array this.CTStore is a comparison transcript for a dialogue.

```js
    private processMatching(): void {
    
            // Check if stored values and dialog options are available
            if (this.cTStore.length !== 0 && this.readOption!.length !== 0) {
    
                // Iterate through stored values to find the best match
                for (const value of this.cTStore) {
                    const bestMatchIndex = this.findBestMatchIndex(value.toLowerCase());
                    // Update current best matches if a match is found
                    if (bestMatchIndex !== -1) {
                        if (this.readOption!.length == 5) {
                            this.readOption![bestMatchIndex].width = 288;
                        } else if (this.readOption!.length == 4) {
                            this.readOption![bestMatchIndex].width = 315;
                        } else if (this.readOption!.length == 3) {
                            this.readOption![bestMatchIndex].width = 220;
                        } else if (this.readOption!.length == 2) {
                            this.readOption![bestMatchIndex].width = 220;
                        }
                        this.currentBestMatches.push({
                            x: this.readOption![bestMatchIndex].x,
                            y: this.readOption![bestMatchIndex].y,
                            width: this.readOption![bestMatchIndex].width,
                            buttonX: this.readOption![bestMatchIndex].buttonx,
                            displayIndex: this.currentBestMatches.length,
                        });                 
                        this.emit("change", this.getCState());
                        this.anyOption = false;
                    } else if (
                        bestMatchIndex < 0 &&
                        value === "[Any option]" &&
                        this.readOption?.every((option) => option.text !== "[Any option]") &&
                        this.currentBestMatches &&
                        this.currentBestMatches.length === 0
                    ) {
                        const randomIndex = Math.floor(
                            Math.random() * this.readOption!.length
                        );
                        if (this.readOption!.length == 5) {
                            this.readOption![randomIndex].width = 288;
                        } else if (this.readOption!.length == 4) {
                            this.readOption![randomIndex].width = 315;
                        } else if (this.readOption!.length == 3) {
                            this.readOption![randomIndex].width = 220;
                        } else if (this.readOption!.length == 2) {
                            this.readOption![randomIndex].width = 220;
                        }
                        this.currentBestMatches.push({
                            x: this.readOption![randomIndex].x,
                            y: this.readOption![randomIndex].y,
                            width: this.readOption![randomIndex].width,
                            buttonX: this.readOption![randomIndex].buttonx,
                            displayIndex: this.currentBestMatches.length,
                        });
                        this.emit("change", this.getCState());
                        this.anyOption = true;
                    }
                }
    
                // Populate unique coordinates based on the current best matches
                this.populateUniqueCoordinates();
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.dialogHelp.find();
                }, 2000);
    
                // console.warn(
                //  "Transcript Could not be found because there are no readoptions on screen"
                // );
            }
        }
```

this is the function that handles my logic behind my program. It currently is able to detect options that are unique on the screen and any options that are not in the comparison transcript which is a 49 word JSON Object.
If any of you want to see my solution it can be replicated by running the comparison string values through this:

```
    private findBestMatchIndex(value: string): number {
            let bestMatchDistance = Infinity;
            let bestMatchIndex = -1;
    
            for (let i = 0; i < this.readOption!.length; i++) {
                const option = this.readOption![i].text.toLowerCase();
                const distance = this.levenshteinDistance(value, option);
                            //To say I need an exact match
                const similarityThreshold = 0;
    
                if (distance <= similarityThreshold && distance < bestMatchDistance) {
                    bestMatchDistance = distance;
                    bestMatchIndex = i;
                }
            }
    
            return bestMatchIndex;
        }
```

It enters this function then gets matched with this function which gets passed alog to this for a comparison.

```
    public levenshteinDistance(a: string, b: string): number {
            const matrix: number[][] = [];
    
            // Initialize matrix with 0-based index values
            for (let i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
                matrix[i] = [i];
            }
            for (let j = 0; j <= b.length; j++) {
                matrix[0][j] = j;
            }
    
            // Fill the matrix
            for (let i = 1; i <= a.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 1; j <= b.length; j++) {
                    const cost = a[i - 1] === b[j - 1] ? 0 : 1;
                    matrix[i][j] = Math.min(
                        matrix[i - 1][j] + 1, // Deletion
                        matrix[i][j - 1] + 1, // Insertion
                        matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + cost // Substitution
                    );
                }
            }
    
        // Return the bottom-right value of the matrix
        return matrix[a.length][b.length];
    }
```

You will be able to now get the exact solution I am getting
example:

[image: In this image is a word that appear in order in the JSON OBject]

```
    {
        "Dialogue": [
            "The who with the what now?",
            "I guess I have one of those faces.",
            "Saradomin must have had a good reason...",
            "(Kneel before Saradomin.)",
            "How can I help?",
            "[Accept Quest]",
            "Yes, teleport us to the Black Knights' Fortress.",
            "No, I have something...special planned for him.",
            "Are you suggesting I cannot handle a mere knight of Saradomin?",
            "What do you want, maggot?",
            "This prisoner is to be sacraficed.",
            "Yes.",
            "I shall return after I deal with this Temple Knight",
            "I am bringing him to the tallest tower.",
            "We need him to recover the weapon of power, as you know.",
            "Stand aside. I will handle this.",
            "The prisoner stays with me.",
            "Pick up the grimoire.",
            "Replace the candle.",
            "Arom.",
            "Nahrea.",
            "Imperium.",
            "Feritas.",
            "Silenti.",
            "Sepulchrum.",
            "Igasac.",
            "Perdimit.",
            "Ebulam.",
            "Yes, enter the portal.",
            "Where are we?",
            "Who's Saint Elspeth?",
            "How did the Kinshra capture you?",
            "Continue.",
            "Let's take her with us.",
            "I am ready to be judged.",
            "I fight to protect the innocent.",
            "I'm ready.",
            "I am ready to be judged.",
            "I fight to protect the innocent.",
            "I'm ready.",
            "Give me the wand or you won't live to regret it.",
            "Continue",
            "I've made my decision.",
            "I will give you the wand.",
            "Were we too late?",
            "[Any option]",
            "Why would you help us?",
            "[Any option]"
        ]
    }
```

this is my JSON object. The reason I am here is because I have spent hours and hours trying to figure out to to shift my array of words dynamically. It currently is not able to. It will pick Arom. Nahrea. Imperium. which is the correct order for the first set of options which is great.
The next set of correct options are Feritas Silenti. and Sepulchrum. But it will pick automatically what has already been chosen Nahrea, Then it will pick Silenti, Then Silenti again. When I need it to pick Feritas, Silenti, Sepulchrum. I need to figure out a way to shift to the correct options instead of just seeing them how they appear in the dialogue. I have tried many different ways so far:

1. Cyclic Shifting:

```
    private cyclicShift(
            arr: any[],
            shiftCount: number,
            startIndex: number
        ): any[] {
            const shiftedArr = [...arr];
            for (let i = 0; i < shiftCount; i++) {
                const frontItem = shiftedArr.splice(startIndex, 1)[0];
                shiftedArr.splice(
                    (startIndex + shiftCount - 1) % shiftedArr.length,
                    0,
                    frontItem
                );
            }
            return shiftedArr;
    }
```

this has provided me the closest result I can come to. I have tried just shifting the array to the index of the next word as well.

[[image: Example of it choosing an option based on index of the comparison object.]]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqMa1.png)

[[image: Correct Option chosen because it appears first]]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/56B18.png)

[[image: Option is not correctly chosen because of the way it appears in the array. It sees one word first and chooses.]]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGR19.png)

If you guys can help me out and maybe find me a solution I would really appreciate it. Ive been digging at this for about 8 hours. Options come in pairs of three. First word, second word  third word move on.